# Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate : can't update an array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongoose and i have a problem.
In my app, i have a Travel model like this:

```
const travelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Please add a title'],
    trim: true,
    maxlength: [50, 'Title can not be more than 50 characters'],
  },
  cities: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'City',
    },
  ],
});
```

and a City model like this :

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  location: {
    type: {
      type: String,
      enum: ['Point'],
      required: true,
    },
    coordinates: {
      type: [Number],
      required: true,
    },
  },
  travels: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Travel',
    },
  ],
});
```

So when i delete a travel, i want to remove the travel_id from the 'travels' field of the cities  which are concerned by the travel.

Here i am:

```
exports.deleteTravel = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const travel = await Travel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
  travel.cities.map(cityId => {
    City.findByIdAndUpdate(
      cityId,
      { travels: travels.filter(id => id !== travel._id) },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      }
    );
  });


  res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: {} });
});
```

I got this error message: Error: travels is not defined

Do you have any idea why?

Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's working like this :)

```
exports.deleteTravel = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const travel = await Travel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
  travel.cities.map(async cityId => {
    await City.findByIdAndUpdate(
      cityId,
      { $pull: { travels: travel._id } },
      {
        new: true,
        runValidators: true,
      }
    );
  });
```